# Get exact rows when left join with another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

My query is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW saledetailfortax AS 
    SELECT
        sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid, sd.productid,
        sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno, sd.mrp, sd.totalprice, sd.qty, 
        sd.looseqty, ord.priceperunit as priceperunit, ord.taxid  
    FROM
        saledetail sd LEFT JOIN orvrcvdetailfortax ord
                                ON sd.productid = ord.productid
                                    AND sd.expdate = ord.expdate
                                    AND sd.batchno = ord.batchno
                                    AND sd.mrp = ord.mrp
    WHERE sd.saledetaildate <= '2016-03-31'
    ORDER BY  sd.saledetaildate , sd.saledetailtime;
```

here when execute it it returns more rows than execute this query :

```
SELECT
    sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid,
    sd.productid,sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno,
    sd.mrp, sd.totalprice, sd.qty, sd.looseqty
FROM saledetail sd
WHERE sd.saledetaildate <= '2016-03-31'
ORDER BY sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime;
```

My aim is to retrieve rows from `saledetail` table and find out its corresponding
`priceperunit, taxid where  productid, expdate, batchno, mrp` match.

problem is with same `(productid, expdate, batchno, mrp)` different `taxid` exit so record comes more than desire. How to reduce it.

Comment: The obvious answer would be to use the correct `join` conditions so you have a 1-1 match.  What those are is entirely unclear, because you provide no information in the question that can help determine which matching row is the right one.

Comment: As your question is so ambiguous, so i am guessing you can try using "GROUP BY" to remove repeating rows.

Comment: Please don't use `GROUP BY` (or `DISTINCT`) without understanding **why** you have duplicate rows.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff says, please provide more information. Table structures, sample data, expected output for that sample data. A good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tom H, duplicate rows due to different taxid with same productid , expdate , batchno , mrp

Comment: ... table structures, sample data, expected output for that sample data. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW saledetailfortax AS
    SELECT
        sd.saledetaildate, sd.saledetailtime, sd.shopid, sd.productid,
        sd.unitid, sd.expdate, sd.batchno, sd.mrp, sd.totalprice,
        sd.qty, sd.looseqty, ord.priceperunit as priceperunit, ord.taxid
    FROM saledetail sd LEFT JOIN orvrcvdetailfortax ord
                            ON sd.productid = ord.productid
    WHERE sd.saledetaildate <= '2016-03-31'
    ORDER BY sd.saledetaildate , sd.saledetailtime;
```

You Have to write only one 2 condition after on like above

other send me data of both table